# Serialize class to json as array

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Using `Json.Net 5.0.5` I would like to serialize this class

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class RingPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }

    public double Y { get; set; }

    public RingPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public double[] Location { get { return new[] { X, Y }; } }

    public bool Equals(RingPoint obj)
    {
        return obj != null && obj.X == X && obj.Y == Y;
    }
}
```

to this json format

```
{"rings":[[[0.0,0.0],[1.0,0.0],[2.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0]]]}
```

normal serialization gives me

```
{"rings":[[{"Location":[0.0,0.0]},{"Location":[1.0,0.0]},{"Location":[2.0,0.0]},{"Location":[0.0,0.0]}]]}
```

It's pretty simple to do with a custom converter but is there an attribute way to do this or is this the perfect example of when to use a JsonConverter

```
public class RingPointConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        writer.WriteValue(((RingPoint)value).X);
        writer.WriteValue(((RingPoint)value).Y);
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (RingPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom converter is not necessary if your class were defined differently. Your class actually needs to be something like this;

```
public class rings
{
    List<List<List<double>>> rings;
}
```

Which is disgusting... but in order for the default JsonConverter to correctly serialize it you need an array/list of doubles inside of a list that's inside of a list. I don't even want to begin writing the code to add values to that. By the way, arrays and List are handled the same by the JsonConverter, I chose to use lists because I don't know what the syntax would be for arrays (I don't think it exists).

Anyways, your custom converter is probably a better approach. It's cleaner and makes more sense. Trying to populate that list would just be a pain in the ass.

Comment: It would just be a jagged array: 
`double[][][] rings = new double[1][][];
rings[0] = new double[1][];
rings[0][0] = new double[1];
rings[0][0][0] = 3.4;`. Not that I'd recommend doing it... :)

Comment: @JoeEnos that makes sense and I was thinking that might be it. Then I started thinking of the way the lists are nested and confused myself.